# Solution to Parametric Equation of Intersection of Plane and Line

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have inserted an image of the question I am trying to solve below first, and I'll say how I have (fruitlessly) tried to solve it.

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS2Jf.jpg)

What I did was I plugged in the x, y, and z in terms of 't' into the equation of the plane (which looks more like an equation for a line). I do this with the intention of finding the value for t where the 'plane' and line intersect. Every time I do this I get -25=-25, which seems to suggest that 't' is free, but when I plug in the point with any random 't' value WebAssign says it is wrong.

Can anyone give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong. You have taken exactly the right approach.

However, you must bear in mind that there are three possibilities when we come to consider the intersection of a line and a plane.

1) There may be no intersection. Geometrically this would be when the line is hovering a fixed distance above the plane. In terms of trying to solve the equations, you would end up with a statement like $20=25$ that would never be true.

2) There is exactly one point of intersection. Geometrically this would be when the line plunges down through tghe plane and out the other side. In such cases you would indeed end up with a linear equation in $t$ that could be solved and that one particular value of $t$ could be used to identiofy the single point of intersection.

3) There are an infinite number of points of intersection. Geometrically this is where the line lies in the plane. That is what has happened in this case. As you have noted, the statement "-25 = -25" is true for all values of $t$ and is in fact free or independent of $t$. The intersection is thus the line.

Your only mistake is to try to enter a single point as the intersection. The intersection is the set of all points that are on the line. You can describe these just exactly as the line was described or as a general point with coordinates $(5+8t,4+3t,-4-2t)$.

Comment: Thank you for you comprehensive response, tomi! The problem I am encountering is that when I entered than into WebAssign (the online tool we use for these homeworks), it tells me that's wrong - which I know it isn't. But that's for me to figure out, I suppose. Thank you once again!

Comment: Can you enter a whole line of text? In which case enter "x=5+8t, y=4+3t, z=-4-2t"

Comment: Unfortunately, it only lets me enter the coordinates, which I did and it won't seem to accept in any configuration. That's alright though, I'm mostly content with knowing the answer to the question.

Comment: Can you enter the coords as algebra? How annoying!

Comment: It does let me enter them as algebra, but even when I do enter exactly what we got $(5+8t, 4+3t, -4-2t)$ it doesn't accept the answer